# Are there any high voltage (14V) MCUs?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-regulator

Switching regulators and LDOs are not an option, for complex reasons.

Are there any MCUs which can tolerate a 14V supply voltage?

I'm currently looking at 4000 series logic to do what I need, but I would much prefer an MCU.

Comment: Well it can't be a space constrain if you are considering 4000 logic. Go on, I'm intrigued - say why regulators can't be used.

Comment: Microchip has some HV chips, that can be fed a higher voltage directly. But they regulate it down, they don't *run* at that voltage. (And I am as intrigued as Andy about your complex reasons).

Comment: It's programmer (me) vs circuit designer discussion.  I prefer systems under software control.  Others prefer extreme efficiency.

Comment: complex reasons == I just don't want them?

Comment: If regulators aren't allowed, for reasons unknown, I guess the only option is to burn away with two resistors as a voltage divider. This does of course assume that the input voltage is stable. Though of course, this is nearly as bad design as using a PIC in the 2010's. Ask your hw guy why he insists on a bad hw design.

Comment: Are you somehow implying that "software control" implies that direct operation from 14V is required? That just doesn't make any sense. And in any case, it wouldn't be just the supply voltage that would be high; all of the input and output signals would have to be at the higher voltage as well.

Comment: You can use a plain old 78M05 or a zener and a resistor (the HV PICs have the zener effectively inside). Neither solution is an LDO or a switching regulator, and you'll find the efficiency refreshingly miserable. Alternatively, some PICs etc. have part of a switching regulator on- board, that is under software control. You can implement this without the specialized on-chip peripherals, at some loss in robustness (i.e. it could b*gger up and fry everything in case of a SEU).

Comment: Why would a programmer discuss the circuit implementation with the circuit designer? The circuit designer is there precisely to spare you the techy details...

Comment: So you prefer systems under software control, and are looking at 4000 series logic?

Answer (score 2):

Microchip's [PIC12HV range](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC12F615) can take up to 15V.

There are more options from Microchip, like the [PIC16HV540](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC16HV540).

Comment: It seems that they are still *operating* at max. 5.5V (thers's just a regulator on the chip).

Comment: @Curd That's correct, but OP asked me to post my comment as an answer, which I've done. Only *he* knows if it's useful I guess.

Comment: Most MCUs do have internal regulators, generally operating at lower voltage internally, than what is given as supply and external logic levels.

Comment: @Curd In this case, it doesn't really matter what the chip runs at internally for the OP's design, I would assume the important thing is the input voltages can go as high as 14v in his case (which it can for PortB of the PIC16HV540. but not Port A).

Comment: @tcrosley: how do YOU know what matters for the OP? The fact that he explicitly doesn't want to use a voltage regulator suggests to me that he want's the core to run at the high voltage. Of course the straight forward solution would be to use level converters and a CPU at lower voltage, but obviously this is not what the OP wants since he is even considering using discrete logic working at 14V.

Comment: @Curd "The fact that he explicitly doesn't want to use a voltage regulator suggests to me that he want's the core to run at the high voltage."  He doesn't say that, he just wants Vdd to be at a higher voltage.  Guess we'll just disagree on this.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I know is the [CDP1802](http://www.cedmagic.com/tech-info/data/cdp1802-cosmac.pdf) that is able to run at 10V.

According to [another datasheet](https://archive.org/stream/SSS-CDP1802COSMACMicroprocessorDataSheetOCR/SSS-CDP1802COSMACMicroprocessorDataSheetOCR_djvu.txt) there is/was also a variant CDP1802D that works with up to 12V.

They are used for high reliablity application, e.g. [onboard of some spacecraft and satellites (e.g. Galileo)](http://www.retrotechnology.com/memship/1802_spacecraft.html).